# Error while running 'update-database' command on .NET Core Oracle.EntityframeworkCore

Tags: c#, oracle, ef-code-first, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to add tables to an oracle database using EFCore code-first approach. I have successfully run the **'add-migration'** command but when running **'update-database'** on my nuget package manager console, I get an oracle error: **'ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS Keyword, ORA-06512: at line 2'** error. I have tried all I can think of. Everyone is suggesting using the database-first approach but I really want the code-first approach to work.

My Nuget packages are:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (2.2.6)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (2.2.6)
Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore (2.19.30)
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core (2.19.31)
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Guys, this error just occurs when there is an Identity Column Included. I converted the datatype to a Guid and it worked. Immediately it is converted to an int field, it throws the error..

Comment: Could you elaborate more? give some code samples? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example